# javascript getting the value of a text box

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have this text box here...

```
<input name="search" type="text" maxlength="512" id="search" class="searchField" autocomplete="off" title="" />
```

and I also have this submit

```
<input type="submit" name="btnSearch" value="Search" onclick="location.href='http://www.website.com/search/';" id="btnSearch" class="buttonSearch" />
```

what I am trying to do is add whatever is in the text box in my

```
onclick="location.href='http://www.website.com/search/';"
```

so it would look like this..

```
onclick="location.href='http://www.website.com/search/what ever the user searches';"
```

how would I go about doing this, I have been googling my little heart out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work:

```
onclick="location.href='http://www.website.com/search/'+document.getElementById('search').value;"
```

**But I wouldn't ever write that in one of my project as writing script directly on tags is a bad practice.**

Comment: then why are you posting this as an answer? It's best, in my opinion, to try to discourage bad practices whenever possible

Comment: It might be someone that is still learning about JavaScript. Best practices should be followed, but are not mandatory.

Answer (score 11):

Please avoid mixing JavaScript and HTML. You can remove `onclick` attribute and replace it with this in plain JavaScript somewhere after the DOM has loaded:

```
document.getElementById('btnSearch').onclick = function() {
    var search = document.getElementById('search').value;
    var searchEncoded = encodeURIComponent(search);
    window.location.url = "http://www.website.com/search/" + searchEncoded;
}
```

Also remember about escaping the search box, e.g. using `encodeURIComponent()`. Here is a [working jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/nurkiewicz/D8Ann/).

Comment: Hmm.. I googled escape vs encodeURIComponent.  Learned something today. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [a working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jyrL4/)

I moved the event handler out of the button as it is more maintainable.  Also I encode the search query so that it gets to the server properly.

```
var search = document.getElementById('search');
var submit = document.getElementById('btnSearch');

submit.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var searchValue = encodeURIComponent(search.value);  // encode the search query
    window.location.href = 'http://www.website.com/search/' + searchValue ;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to the onclick event like so

```
document.getEelementById("btnSearch").onclick = function(){
    location.href='http://www.website.com/search/' + document.getEelementById("search").value;
}
```

edit: aaaaand too slow... oh well.  At least this is not inline.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using the < script> tag for this task. Example:

```
<input name="search" type="text" maxlength="512" id="search" class="searchField" autocomplete="off" title="" />
...
<input type="submit" name="btnSearch" value="Search"  id="btnSearch" class="buttonSearch" />
<script type="text/javascript">
var button= document.getElementById('btnSearch');
button.onclick= function(){
    var text= document.getElementById('search').value;
    location.href='http://www.website.com/search/'+text;
}
</script>
```

However, you should try to 'clean' a little the text from the textbox so when you append it to the url you get a valid url. You should trim the text, then search for special characters and escape them, etc.